# How to move multiple files in multiple folder in a simple method

Tags: windows, file, cmd, move

I have three images named Apple, Banana, Orange
and I also have three folders according to the same name.
And all the files and all the empty folders are on the same path.
Now I want to create a way which can help me to automatically move all the files in the same-named folder.
How to do that?

Comment: `for /?` (especially the 'modifiers' section), `move /?`. Maybe also `if /?` (`if exist`) and `md /?`

Answer (score 0):

Use the for loop to do this:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('dir /b /a-d') do move "%%f" "%%~nf"
```

If you want any file containing "Apple" to be moved to the "Apple" folder, as well as any file containing "Orange" to the "Orange" folder, etc. (even if they contain additional characters in their name such as Apple_1, apple001, green-apple etc.), use the following syntax:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%d in ('dir /b /ad') do for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('dir /b /a-d "*%%d*"') do move "%%f" "%%d"
```